# All run/debug options disabled in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, virtualbox, rubymine

I'm running RubyMine on an Ubuntu 12.04 Virtualbox and I can run the rails server fine from the command line.  However, all of the run/debug options are completely disabled in RubyMine.  I can't even create a new run configuration.

Could this be due to running it on Virtualbox?

Comment: Please clarify with a screenshot. Edit configurations option should be available. Make sure indexing is complete, try `File` | `Invalidate Caches`, ensure caches are not in the encrypted folder: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This happened to me and the issue was resolved by following these steps:

1. Close RubyMine
2. Delete the .idea folder from your project directory
3. Re-open RubyMine and open your project directory
4. RubyMine should auto-detect the existing Rails app and create default launch configurations

Answer (score 1):

I too had a crash of RubyMine but deleting the .idea folder did not work for me - after reopening RubyMine the options were still disabled.

After a bit of research I realized, that the run configurations are built after the project is indexed. Clicking on the progress bar in the status bar on the bottom of the Window shows the progress of the background tasks. Waiting until all tasks are completed solved the issue for me.